# Erro 403 ao tentar "sincronizar o projeto com o Gradle"

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Quando abro o Android Studio, ele não consegue sincronizar o projeto com esse "Gradle", ele retorna o seguinte erro no "Messages Gradle Sync"

> Error:
>   `Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.12.2/gradle-0.12.2.jar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
>   Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project`

Imagem:

[image: Imagem do erro]

**<sub>build.gradle:</sub>**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**<sub>gradle-wrapper.properties</sub>**

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

Vocês sabem o que pode ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Me parece que o Jcenter ainda não tem os pacotes do `com.android.tools.build` que é usado no Gradle para construir o apk</del>.

Os pacotes existem (a url para ele é: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.12.2/#gradle-0.12.2.jar), mas o gradle ou o Android Studio está com algum problema para obter esses pacotes (protocolo ou algo do tipo), o que gera o erro `403`.

Troque o repositório `jcenter` da definição de `buildscript` por `mavenCentral`. Esse é um bug que possui um [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73511) que não foi resolvido ainda.

Seu build.gradle deve ficar:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Troquei o jcenter pelo mavenCentral. Depois que o issue for resolvido, pode voltar ao normal
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

O fato de usar o `mavenCentral` na definição de repositório para todos os projetos não afeta o repositório usado para o `buildscript`, pela definição do `buildscript` ser mais específica.

Comment: muito bom parabens

Comment: `"Depois que o issue for resolvido, pode voltar ao normal"`. É obrigatório voltar ao normal?

Comment: Não é obrigatório, eu usava o `mavenCentral`, mas me parece que eles (a Google) está "forçando` a migração para o `jcenter` por alguma razão (não sei ainda). Essa migração é vista quando você cria um projeto Android novo no Android Studio e ele coloca o `jcenter` como padrão em vez do `mavenCentral` (que era o padrão anterior). Essa [pergunta do SO EN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852219/android-buildscript-repositories-jcenter-vs-mavencentral) comenta sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver em uma rede com firewall pode ser este o problema seguindo a solução

No Android Studio va em `File>Settings>Gradle>Global Gradle Settings` e no `Gradle VM options` e  específique os dados do proxy:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=dummyHost -Dhttp.proxyPort=dummyPort -Dhttp.proxyUser=dummyUser -Dhttp.proxyPassword=dummyPassword
```

Preenchendo com seus dados é claro.

Comment: espero ter ajudado

Comment: Eu acho que a rede da empresa não possui `Proxy`. Como faço pra descobrir? Aqui nas configurações está com proxy automático.

Comment: precisaria ver com alguem que tenha o conhecimento na empresa para ver se tem proxy ou se tem algum tipo de bloqueio caso proxy transparente. pelo que pesquiser esse seu erro é devido a isto